# Como pasar el nombre de un atributo de un objeto por parámetros en Js?

Tags: javascript, poo, funciones, parametros

Necesito hacer una función en JavaScript que pase un numero y un string como parámetro y que me devuelva algo así:

arregloDeObjetos(5, “hola”) debe retornar [{hola: 1}, {hola: 2}, {hola: 3}, {hola: 4}, {hola: 5 }]

Pero cuando lo hago toma como nombre del atributo el nombre de la variable en si y no el contenido, Me frustre de no encontrar la manera.
Hice esto hasta ahora

```
function arregloDeObjetos(cantidad, msj){
let arregloObj = []

for(let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++ ){
    arregloObj[i] = //???
}

return arregloObj
```

}

Comment: Hola, no logro entender muy bien... **por ejemplo**, ¿¿..si le doy esto a la función `(3, 'algo')` debería darme `['algo': 1, 'algo': 2, 'algo': 3]`..??

Comment: Por otro lado, por favor comenta tu código de ejemplo y explica que intentas hacer en cada paso. ademas te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganar tu primera medalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear atributos a partir de un string puedes usar la sintaxis `{ [key]: value }`

Algunos ejemplos:

```js
const key = 'hola'

// equivalente a usar { hola: 23 }
const obj = { [key] : 23 }
console.log(obj)

// equivalente a usar
// obj2 = { boop: 3.14 }
const obj2 = { ['bo' + 'op'] : 3.14 }
console.log(obj2)
```

Lo que nos permite crear propiedades calculadas con mucha facilidad:

```js
function arregloDeObjetos(cantidad, msj) {
    let arregloObj = []

    for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        arregloObj[i] = {[msj]: i + 1}
    }

    return arregloObj
}

console.log(arregloDeObjetos(5, 'hola'))
```

Puedes ver más del tema [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias me sirvio mucho, hace poco empece con js y me cuesta un toque jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Ese ejercicio de vi para un bootcamp lo realice asi amigo:

```
function arregloDeObjetos(num,palabra){
  let arra = [];
  let msj = '';
  for(let i=1;i<=num;i++){
    msj = `{${palabra}: ${i}}`;
    arra.push(msj);
  }
  return arra;
}
arregloDeObjetos(5,'hola');
```

declaro un arreglo vacio llamado arra, despues una cadena vacia ''.
en el for recorro desde 1 hasta el numero donde despues voy a concatenar la palabra y el indice y lo voy almacenar en el arreglo para al final mostrarlo:

```
// arregloDeObjetos(5, “hola”) debe retornar [{hola: 1}, {hola: 2}, {hola: 3}, {hola: 4}, {hola: 5 }]
// arregloDeObjetos(3, “chau”) debe retornar [{chau: 1}, {chau: 2}, {chau: 3}]
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder a esta pregunta amigo. Pero para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida, te recomiendo pasar esos pasos que tienes allí como comentarios en cada parte del código, explicando lo que hace. Se vera y enterara mejor ;) un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho!!!!